# coredata fetch list from one table and details from another without relation

Tags: ios, core-data

i have two entity

First one -

```
{
          "ID": 5777,
          "Name": "",
          "EventID": 18341,
          "ParentID": 19702,
          "LastModifiedDate": "2016-11-30 09:36:04",
          "EntityType": 3,
          "InstanceID": 916787
        }
```

2d one

```
{
          "ID": 19702,
          "Name": "Google",
          "EventID": 18341,
          "ParentID": 0,
          "LastModifiedDate": "2016-12-01 06:20:49",
          "EntityType": 0,
          "FileAttribute": "",
          "InstanceID": 0,
          "IsFile": false,
          "ResourceURL": "http://www.google.com",
          "Taxonomies": "0",
          "ViewCount": 2
        }
```

Now need to fetch from 2nd one with "ID" is  "ParentID" of first one using core data.

```
MySql query will "SELECT * FROM "tbl_two" WHERE `ID` IN ( SELECT `ParentID` FROM "tbl_ONE" WHERE `InstanceID` = '916787' AND `EventID` = '18341')
```

Comment: Trying to do this in Core Data without a relationship is literally the same thing as trying to make your work more difficult than it needs to be.

Comment: hi, @TomHarrington . I am new in ios development and hardly know in depth of core data. Can u please help me how it need to be done .. two table is there "resource" and "resourcemapping" .. "resourcemapping" is related to user

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to **stop thinking about Core Data like it's SQL**. It has a different API, and thinking in SQL terms will lead you to poor designs.

In the most general terms, don't think of records, think of objects that you might use in an app and how those objects relate to each other. Instead of using foreign keys to relate one record to another, use object properties to relate one object to another.

From what I can make of your SQL query, you want something like

- Two Core Data entities called `Resource` (your first sample) and `ResourceMapping` (your second sample).
- `Resource` has a property called something like `mapping`, of type `ResourceMapping`.
- You relate one to another **using the relationship**, not by ID. You can store the IDs if you need to sync the data to a remote server but they're usually not useful in Core Data.

The equivalent of your SQL query would be, I think:

1. Fetch the single instance of `Resource` (the first example) using an `NSPredicate` that matches one or more of its properties.
2. When you have that instance, ask it for the value of its relationship `mapping` (or whatever you call it), and you'll get the related object from the other entity.

Beyond that, Apple provides [extensive, detailed documentation with code samples](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/) that will help.